# How do I mock my Webservice?

Tags: c#, wcf, mocking

I need to make tests for my webservice project. In my webservice Interface there is a method named `loginuser` with string params `username` and `password`. It uses C#, WCF, and Visual Studio.

How do I to test that loginuser method in my webservice returns correct results?

Comment: "your web service is worthless and weak!" usually works...oh, wait, nevermind ;-)

Comment: My web service consumes a lot of resources, so i'm more partial to calling it "fatty"

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be talking about 2 different things:

- Mocking your web service
- Testing your web service

For mocking of a web / wcf service, we normally create a service that implements the same interface, but returns hard coded values.

For testing web services we do it in two ways:

- Test the dll directly for functionality
- Test the service via the proxy layer, of the project that is to use the service

Answer (score 0):

[WCFMock](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/03/08/wcfmock-a-mocking-framework-for-wcf-services.aspx), a mocking framework for WCF services.

[Mocking web services with SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/userguide/mock/index.html)

Comment: I do not get why you can't set properties for the content type or add data to the body of the mocked HttpRequest.  E.g. mockContext.VerifySet(c => c.IncomingRequest.ContentType = "application/atom+xml");  the properties are read-only for Incoming request but not for outgoing...not sure why